# Как создать новый список из фаила .txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание состоит в следующем:

Дан файл names.txt

1. Нужно написать функцию, которая считывает данные из этого файла,
   возвращая СПИСОК тех строк в которых есть полная дата, писатель и указание на его день рождения или смерти.
2. Нужно написать функцию, которая принимает список строк полученной в пункте 1, и возвращает список словарей
   в формате {"name": name, "date": date},
   где name это имя автора, а date - дата из строки в формате "dd/mm/yyyy" (d-день, m-месяц, y-год)
   `Например:  [{"name": Dr. Seuss, "date": 02/03/1904}, {"name": Jules Verne, "date": 24/03/1905}...]`

Например, кусок из фаила:

```
2nd March 1904 - Dr. Seuss's birthday, author of Cat in the Hat
3rd March 2016 - World Book Day 2016
21st March - World Poetry Day
24th March 1905 - Jules Verne's death, author of Around the World in Eighty Days
31st March 1855 - Charlotte Bronte's death - Author of Jane Eyre
```

Я написал следующее:

```
def read_txt(filename = "authors.txt"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        data = []
        for line in file.readlines():
            if line.find("birthday") or line.find("death"):
                data.append(line)
    return data
print(read_txt())
```

Вот только выводит все равно все строки.

Как это исправить? Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция [str.find("text")](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) - возвращает `-1` в том случае если ничего не найдено.

Проверка `if -1:` - возвращает `True`.

Таким образом проверка `line.find("birthday") or line.find("death")` - всегда возвращает `True`.

Воспроизведение:

```
In [178]: if -1:
     ...:     print("What ??")
     ...: 
What ??

In [179]: if "aaa".find("bbb"):
     ...:     print("What ??")
     ...: 
What ??
```

Comment: А как тогда лучше сделать?

Comment: @Stud200891, как тогда лучше сделать __что__?

Comment: как создать список только с нужными мне строками?

Comment: @Stud200891, сравнивать `line.find(...) >= 0`

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А можете помочь со вторым пунктом?

Comment: @Stud200891, приведите в вопросе пример результата, который вы хотите получить для приведенных в вопросе входных данных...

Comment: [{"name": Dr. Seuss, "date": 02/03/1904}, {"name": Jules Verne, "date": 24/03/1905}...]

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118216/discussion-between-stud200891-and-maxu).